# How to return a result from a payload preview using python requests

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header)

decoded = r.json() # EXCEPTION ERROR: 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'
if decoded.get("error") == 1:
    print("C Status:\033[92mLIVE\033[0m\n\n")
if decoded.get("error") == 2:
    print("C Status:\033[31mDEAD\033[0m\n\n")
if decoded.get("error") == 3:
    print("C Status:\033[35mUNKNOWN\033[0m\n\n")
if decoded.get("error") == 4:
    print("\033[41mINVALID INPUT - USE PROPER FORMAT!\033[0m\n\n")
```

This code used to work and it would decode the response generated when i send my post request. The post request still works properly but now the line reading "decoded = r.json()" generates a new error that crashes my program: "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" Unfortunately this is very broad and does not help me (little coding experience) to figure out a fix. I have been browsing for hours trying to fix it but to no avail. Thanks for reading

Comment: It means the website response did not have any json.  Try printing `r.content` to see if it contains an error message.

Comment: Yes it seems to be failing a cloudflare check? not sure. maybe this response from r.content will be of more meaning to you? https://pastebin.com/Np6VCfgQ